# WHERE clause not working, code sample included

Tags: php, mysql

I have this MySQL query below. It works fine.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, name, fee, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) 
    * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) 
    + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat), mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat), mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
```

I'm trying to add a `WHERE` Clause as follows and it is not working

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, name, fee, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) 
    * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) 
    + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM markers WHERE show <> 0 HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat), mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat), mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
```

`show` is a field that acts as a flag. If it contains a 0, I would like that record to be ignored in the above query. `show` is currently defined as a `TINYINT(1)` in my MySQL database.

Comment: It looks fine to me. If you're getting an error, what's the exact error message?

Comment: @user1883050 , May be you need to backtick the word `show`. Otherwise MySQL may treat it as keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*May be it's a backtick issue :*

I've surrounded the word 'SHOW' by backtick. Here's just the query part. Try this.

```
SELECT id, 
           name, 
           fee, 
           lat, 
           lng, 
           ( 3959 * Acos(Cos(Radians('%s')) * Cos(Radians(lat)) * Cos( 
                         Radians(lng) - Radians('%s')) 
                                  + Sin 
                                  (Radians('%s')) * Sin(Radians(lat))) ) AS distance 
    FROM   markers 
    WHERE  `SHOW` <> 0 
    HAVING distance < '%s' 
    ORDER  BY distance 
    LIMIT  0, 20
```

**Edit :**

Backticks are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are only necessary when the identifier is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), or when the identifier contains whitespace characters or characters beyond a limited set. It is often recommended to avoid using reserved keywords as column or table identifiers when possible, avoiding the quoting issue.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to hear that my guess is correct. :) :) :)

Comment: @user1883050 , Please go through this [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23129/benefits-of-using-backtick-in-mysql-queries) for better understanding .